# How to add “Table continued” with caption in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, word-processing

What I want to do is, if a table is split into two or more pages,
add the original table caption with the word "continued" attached. 
Like this:

[image: example of table split across two pages]

What I do now is add a caption,
then cut & paste it into a no-border header table row. 
Select the first two rows
and set them to "repeat" when the table is broken into multiple pages.

But how can I add additional "continue" word at the beginning? Could I use any "field" that indicates page of table, and use "if" to determine whether to show the word?

Comment: Closely related: [How to split tables that span more than one page, adding ‘‘Continued’’ to caption, in Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/q/1402368/150988)  —  but it isn’t answered.