# How to split tables that span more than one page, adding “Continued” to caption, in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, word-processing

I'm looking for a macro that can take a finished Microsoft Word document, go through and find tables that cover more than one page, split the table, add a page break after the first part of the table, add the correct "continued" to the caption for the second part of the table, then continue moving to the next table that spans more than one page and applying the same fix. Military technical manuals require the "Continued" following the caption, so first part of table would be:

Table 1. Caption.

[first part of table]

———— [page break] ————

Table 1. Caption - Continued.

[second part of table]

Comment: I'm interested in seeing if you can find one. In my experience, mil-spec docs are usually produced with true desktop publishing tools many reasons, proper captioning being among them, and consistent list numbering that works in conjunction with section numbering, and proper cross-referencing (e.g., Section N.n.n.n, "heading text, on page N-nn). I upvoted this in the hopes that someone knows of a macro to properly caption page-broken tables.

Comment: Closely related: [How to add “Table continued” with caption in Microsoft Word?](https://superuser.com/q/1329093/150988) — but it isn’t answered.

Comment: there is a guide for this purpose on the following document. https://www.esd.whs.mil/Portals/54/Documents/DD/iss_process/Breaking_Tables_Across_the_Page.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  I'm looking for an automated way to do it.